# unique optimal plan in $\Gamma_o(\gamma,\nu)$?

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transport

Let $\gamma\in \mathcal{P}(X^2)$ (set of probability measures on $X^2$) and $\mu:=\pi^1_{\#}\gamma$ (first marginal of $\gamma$). Define $$\Gamma_o(\gamma,\nu):=\left\{\eta\in\mathcal{P}(X^3):(\pi^1,\pi^2)_{\#}\eta=\gamma,(\pi^1,\pi^3)_{\#}\eta\in\Gamma_o(\mu,\nu)\right\}.$$
I want to understand why if $\gamma=(i\times\xi)_{\#}\mu$ is induced by a transport map and $\mu$ is absolutely continuous, then $\Gamma_o(\gamma,\nu)$ contains only one element $$\Gamma_o(\gamma,\nu)=\{(i\times\xi\times t_{\mu}^{\nu})_{\#}\mu\}$$

Comment: which properties $X$ has? E.g., is it non branching? Usually this property ensures the uniqueness of the displacement interpolation between your measures

Comment: I am not sure what branching means. Is it that two geodesic that match on $[0,\epsilon)$ must match on there whole interval, i.e. they cannot form multiple "branches"? I am reading "Gradient flows in metric spaces" and it seems that the only condition is that $X$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: ok, which page of the book? I am using it too

Comment: It is on page 14.

Comment: Intuitively, that one (i will call the unique plan $\boldsymbol{\eta}$) is a plan (or a joint distribution if you want) since $\pi^{12}_\sharp\boldsymbol{\eta}=\gamma$ and $\pi^3_\sharp\boldsymbol{\eta}=\nu$ where as you wrote $\nu=\boldsymbol{t}_\mu^\nu$, i.e. $\nu$ is the transport of $\mu$ under $\boldsymbol{t}_\mu^\nu$. To prove the optimality that is quite involved, since on page 14 you are just in the beginning as a summary: on page $242$ you need lot of definitions, like regular measures and other stuff. The uniqueness follows from the theorems in the chapter on optimal transport!

Comment: Btw, the book is indeed really hard. Even the first chapters are not so friendly but with a bit of patience everything is possible. On this topic maybe another source is the Villani's book "Optimal transport, old and new" that has the nice characteristic to have a lot of intuitive explanations! Check also the notes by Ambrosio and Gigli "A user's guide to optimal transport" which, imo, is really well written!

Comment: "the uniqueness follows from the theorems in the chapter on optimal transports" which theorems? I understant that if μ is a regular measure or absolutely continuous then there is a unique transport plan (which is induced by a map) from μ to any other measure on $X$ but then how do you use this in this particular case?

Comment: I just see how the triple joint plan is induced by a map too but how to apply it here i do not know atm, sorry. Certainly the answer is somewhere there in the book